# Circular dependency in dependency injection

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection

we're quite new to DI and we're refactoring our application to use Prism/Unity. We're almost there but got stuck on a circular dependency. I've been reading a lot, there are a lot of similar questions but I'm in doubt as to what would be a 'correct' solution in our situation.

The application is similar to some IDEs. We have a project explorer, search, documents, ... The documents are actually treeviews with nodes of INodeViewModel. Note that the code samples are minimized versions of the real code.

We have a `IDockingService` that manages the tool and document items.

```
public interface IDockingService
{
    INodeViewModelNavigationService NodeViewModelNavigationService { get; }

    ExplorerViewModel ExplorerViewModel { get; }
    SearchViewModel SearchViewModel { get; }

    ReadOnlyCollection<ToolItemViewModel> ToolItemViewModels { get; }
    ReadOnlyCollection<DocumentItemViewModel> DocumentItemViewModels { get; }
}
```

And we have a `ISpecificationViewModelService` that manages all the INodeViewModels and has the connection with the model.

```
public interface ISpecificationViewModelService
{
    INodeViewModel RootX { get; }
    INodeViewModel RootY { get; }
    INodeViewModel RootZ { get; }
}
```

We have two requirements that conflict.

- When a new node is created somewhere we want to navigate to it. Currently we pass `IDockingService` via constructor injection to 
  the concrete `SpecificationViewModelService` implementation and further down to each NodeViewModel.
- Certain tools in the `DockingService` need to know about the `ISpecificationViewModelService`. For example the Explorer needs to display all the roots.

Since `DockingItemService` creates and manages the toolitems such as the Explorer it needs the `ISpecificationViewModelService`. But the `ISpecificationViewModelService` needs the `IDockingService` to be able to navigate to a node. Circular troubles.

Our first attempt didn't have this issue because we let the the tool items be created in the composition root but that didn't seem correct. Instances we not managed together nicely.

From reading around I understand that a factory (or another third class) could help out here. I'm not seeing how yet. I think I understand that the problem is that `DockingService` only needs `SpecificationViewModelService` to create the toolitems and vice versa. A factory could take this circular trouble away but I'm not sure it is a correct solution. The container can only be used in the composition root but wouldn't a facory (which needs the container?) then just be hiding the container and take over its work under a different name?

What would be a correct way to handle this problem?

Comment: It looks like you're not correctly separate the model from the view. Move the "navigation" related methods/data to a new class located in the view.

Comment: You'll have to elaborate on that. Nowhere in my question i see a connection between model & view. This is a WPF application. Navigation can perfectly be triggered from the VM layer. Things like navigation history, manipulation, enabling, navigating from a search result, ... clearly don't belong in the view.

Comment: Cyclic dependencies are an indication that some behavior should be extracted to a separate unit. And yes: I was wrong, the model does not have to do anything with it. Sorry.

Comment: I know that, I stated it in other words in the question. My problem is how I can solve it in a correct way taking care of the concerns I stated.

Comment: IMHO there is no "general advice" possible. It all depends on your concrete (current) implementation...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to significantly abstract from your situation. I'm not sure if this will be the best solution to your problem. It will be *a* solution, but it may be just enabling a poor design. It's hard to tell, but certainly the situation comes up in reasonable designs.

It's quite common that you get in a situation that to build `X` you need `Y`, and to build `Y` you need `X`. Of course, it can't be that conceptually to build `X` you need to have completely built a `Y` and vice versa as then it would be logically impossible to construct the system. Instead, what is really meant is to build one you merely need a way of referring to the other. There are many ways of referring to something that hasn't yet been created. For example, in C you might pass a pointer to allocated but uninitialized memory, or you might pass a string that will be used to look up the created object in a registry.  In a language like Haskell or Scala, one way to solve this is with lazy evaluation. Implementation-wise, this is more or less equivalent to passing around a higher order function with some internal mutable state, or, equivalently, a "factory" object that will memoize the dependency resolution.  This is the approach I'm going to suggest here. I'll use [Autofac](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html)'s terminology and API below, though the idea should be easily be adaptable to other dependency injection frameworks.

```cs
class Lazy<T> where T : class {
    private T _cached = null;
    private IContainer _container;
    public Lazy(Func<IContainer> container) {
        _container = container();
    }
    public T Value {
        get {
            if(_cached != null) return _cached;
            _cached = _container.Resolve<T>();
            _container = null;
            return _cached;
        }
    }
}
```

Here `IContainer` is intended to be the dependency injection container, and `Resolve` does the dependency look-up. I *strongly* recommend against passing the dependency injection container to objects, but in this case I'm viewing `Lazy` as part of the dependency injection framework.  In fact, you should make sure that your dependency injection framework doesn't already provide such functionality. The alternative would be to make a factory for each class you want to lazily inject. The code would be basically identical except that `IContainer` would be replaced by any dependencies and instead of using `Resolve` to create the object you'd use `new`. Alternatively, you could generalize `Lazy` to take an `Action<T>` and just memoize it and then these factory objects would just be singletons that you register in the composition root like: `container.Register(new Lazy<Foo>(() => new Foo()));` The ideal situation would be to [register the open generic](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#open-generic-components) type `Lazy<>`, so that with one registration you could handle all cases. (I have verified that you can make this work with Autofac.)

The upshot of this is that you would depend on `Lazy<IFoo>` instead of `IFoo` and you would access via the `Value` property (but not in the constructor!)

Comment: I think you are hitting the nail right on here. I indeed think I don't need the circularity to construct. I'll reflect on this further, investigate it further and come back on it.

Comment: A small improvement: Currently if `_cached` is populated with `null`, we get a NulReferenceException on the next call to `Value`. This is avoided by replacing `if (_cached != null)` by `if (_container == null)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to, another solution would be to drop your constructor injection, add IServiceProvider constructor injection, and use ActivatorUtilities when you need the docking service like this :

```
var dockingService = (IDockingService)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(this.serviceProvider, typeof(DockingService));
```

Of course this is not the preferred way, and you can't test it properly (as you are instantiating a concrete IDockingService), but it's a solution.